# FittedBox Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am trying to render a dynamic Text widget inside the fittedBox.
if the text to long, it will be decrease font-size and vice versa.

```
child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(color: fontColor, height: 1),
      ),
    ),
```

But i got an error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox.
i seem like, inside fittedBox must be a block with exactly size, but Text widget does not have exactly size. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by using [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package. It is extremely performant and can easily replace `Text`. You can also set an overflow which I think you would want.
Here is an example:

```
SizedBox(
 width:20,
 child:AutoSizeText(
  'The text to display. This is a really long text with a lot of words.',
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 1,
 ),
),
```

Comment: yes, thanks for your advice. But i could not add more library. So do you have any another way to do that?

Comment: @hungnv why can't you add anymore library? At most, AutoSizeText will only increase your app size by a few kb. You also have to build your app in release mode to check its real app size. Usually, a 200mb app in debug mode will turn out to be 5-10mb in release mode.